# If (this) visible - Do this

Tags: jquery, drupal

I have a Drupal Webform with conditions on it to show a fieldset if the user selects "yes" to a number of select options. I would like to hide the submit button and only show it when the fieldset is shown.

What I am looking to achieve is this:

On document Load = Hide button with this selector ".webform-client-form-6848 .webform-submit"

As the user selects some select options, the Webform conditions already show or hide a field set.

When the fieldset ".webform-component-fieldset" is shown to then Show the submit button.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it with jQuery. 
The logic is check all the element inside the html when values changes (I parsed just a div), than apply a visibility condition to your submit button if condition is respected.
If u need example I can try to recover a sample code.

Comment: A better 'drupal' way would probably be to use drupal [states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) in a [form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

Comment: Yes please. That would be v helpful

Comment: @2pha How would I do this?